# How to find API details like URL and credentials for IBM Watson Assistant

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

I would like to create a test script for a IBM Watson Assistant chatbot. So I am using the Assistant V2 API.

Below code is On the IBM Watson Assistant page.

```
import json
from ibm_watson import AssistantV2
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator

authenticator = IAMAuthenticator('{apikey}')
assistant = AssistantV2(
    version='2020-02-05',
    authenticator = authenticator
)

assistant.set_service_url('{url}')

response = assistant.message(
    assistant_id='{assistant_id}',
    session_id='{session_id}',
    input={
        'message_type': 'text',
        'text': 'Hello'
    }
).get_result()

print(json.dumps(response, indent=2))
```

My questions is where {url}, {session_id} are
And also {workspace_id} (for using Assistant V1)?

Comment: I am not sure what you try to ask. Any references to documentation that is unclear or any API you are using?

Comment: I modified question. Specifically, I can't find url, session_id, and workspace_id. I found assistant_id and skill_id. There are too many ids and url...

Answer (score 2):

You can find the URL and API key in the resource page for that service. There you can also create additional credentials. When you open the Watson Assistant UI, there are two tabs on the side. One is for Assistants, the second for Skills. Go to skills and then for a skill, click on the 3-dot-menu and select API details. There you find all necessary information.

See this [IBM Watson Assistant doc page for an introduction to the V2 and V1 APIs](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-api-overview).

Session_id is created in V2 when you [create a session](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v2#create-a-session).

BTW: I wrote a [Python test script for Watson Assistant](https://github.com/data-henrik/watson-conversation-tool) a long time ago. There is one for V1 and one for V2 API.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I found Skill Name, Skill Id, Legacy v1 Workspace URL, Service Credentials Name and Api Key in skill tab. You mean {session_id} is Skill id , and {url} is Legacy v1 Workspace URL? I did it also, but error occurs still..."Error: Resource not found, Code: 404 , X-global-transaction-id:"

Comment: See my updated answer on session_id. You either work with V1 or V2, not with both at the same time.

Comment: Thank you. But when I create session, same error occurs. I'm going to solve it. And one more question, If I use V1, workspace_id is needed. Do you know what it is?

Comment: You create a session using V2 API and by providing an assistant_id. The workspace_id is needed for V1. It is the old term for skill. You find the workspace_id as described in my answer.

Comment: I did it...The problem is URL setting....The URL I need to use is resource URL, not assistant URL. Thank you for your help and patience !